# uwsgi unable to load flask and celery from inside docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, celery, uwsgi

I have been trying to run my flask app via docker but uwsgi is unable to load my application, this error occurs for both celery  and flask.
The weird thing is that, if i run the same code normally (,ie; without using docker), it works as i expect it to.

not sure if i'm missing setting some environment variables for it work as expected, any help would be great, thanks in advance!

**file structure:**

```
├── app
│   ├── blueprints
│   │   ├── ping
│   │   │   ├── api.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   ├── tasks
│   │   │   ├── api.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── service.py
│   ├── factories
│   │   ├── application.py
│   │   ├── celery.py
│   │   ├── extensions.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── logging.py
│   │   ├── mongo_db.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── sentry.py
│   ├── flask_app.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── middlewares
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── authorization.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   ├── before_request
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── set_user.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── teardown_request
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __pycache__
│   │       └── rollback_db_changes.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── logging.yaml
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── utils
│   │   ├── base_models.py
│   │   ├── recommendation_util.py
│   │   ├── redis_util.py
│   └── worker.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── requirements.txt
├── scripts
│   ├── Dockerfile-celery
│   └── Dockerfile-flask
```

**app/flask_app.py:**

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_redis import FlaskRedis

from app.factories.application import setup_app
from app.factories.logging import setup_logging
from app.factories.mongo_db import setup_mongo_db
from app.factories.sentry import setup_sentry
from app.factories.celery import setup_celery

flask_app = setup_app()
CORS(flask_app, expose_headers="*")
setup_logging()
setup_sentry(flask_app)
celery = setup_celery(flask_app)
setup_mongo_db(flask_app)
JWTManager(flask_app)
redis_client = FlaskRedis(flask_app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run()
```

**app/woker.py:**

```
from flask_redis import FlaskRedis

from app.factories.mongo_db import setup_mongo_db
from app.factories.application import setup_app
from app.factories.celery import setup_celery
from app.factories.logging import setup_logging
from app.factories.sentry import setup_sentry

flask_app = setup_app()
setup_logging()
setup_sentry(flask_app)
setup_mongo_db(flask_app)
redis_client = FlaskRedis(flask_app)

celery = setup_celery(flask_app)
```

***docker-compose.yml:***

```
version: '2'
services:
    api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: scripts/Dockerfile-flask
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - redis
        environment:
            - ENVIRONMENT=docker
    worker:
        image: celery
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: scripts/Dockerfile-celery
        environment:
            - ENVIRONMENT=docker
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - redis
    redis:
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        command: [ "redis-server"]
```

**Dockerfile-flask**

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD uwsgi --master --workers 5 --threads 50 --protocol http --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --module app.flask_app:flask_app
```

**Dockerfile-celery**

```
FROM python:3.8
ADD . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD celery -A app.worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug --uid=nobody --gid=nogroup
```

The CMDs in the docker files works as expected when I'm trying to run it normally without using docker-compose, when I run docker-compose up after building it, I get the following Errors:

```
For Celery:

worker_1  | Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
worker_1  | Unable to load celery application.
worker_1  | While trying to load the module app.worker.celery the following error occurred:
worker_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 53, in convert
worker_1  |     return find_app(value)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 384, in find_app
worker_1  |     sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
worker_1  |     module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 100, in import_from_cwd
worker_1  |     return imp(module, package=package)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
worker_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
worker_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
worker_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
worker_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
worker_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.worker'


For Flask:
api_1     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.flask_app'
api_1     | unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)


if i hit the url "http://localhost:5000/v1/ping", I get the following error:
api_1     | --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to set a working directory inside Docker so Python knows where your packages and modules are located:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

I've got a similar swarm that sets up three services and I struggled with this quite a bit. In fact, I've got three "environments": testing, development, and production. And getting the config to play nice was tricky.

As you know, depending on what you set your "app" to (either with `FLASK_APP` or in the uWSGI configuration and where you start your app from matters.

In my case, my `uwsgi.ini` file has this as app module:

```
module = api.main:app
```

My basic structure is like so:

```
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── email.py
│   │   ├── exceptions.py
│   │   ├── files.py
│   │   ├── logging.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   ├── tasks.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── default.py
│   │   ├── development.py
│   │   ├── production.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── conftest.py
│   │   ├── pytest.ini
│   │   ├── tasks.py
│   │   ├── test_app.py
│   │   └── test_tasks.py
│   ├── uwsgi.ini
│   ├── main.py
│   └── worker.py
├── bitbucket-pipelines.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── requirements
│   ├── app.txt
│   └── tests.txt
└── supervisord.conf
```